# Cannot import module in pip freeze list

Tags: virtualenv, pip

I cannot import a module that I see in the pip freeze list (in my case django-olwidget, but I don't think it's nothing to do with this module).

With the virtual environment activated, I:

- uninstalled an old version of the module (0.47)
- confirmed that it is gone from the freeze list
- pip installed the module again
- checked the module is in the freeze list now (django-olwidget==0.50)

The environment is active but, now I cannot import the module. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this question is still relevant, but I had a similar problem which I just asked a question about before realizing the error. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31028990/pip-freeze-gives-different-modules-from-helpmodules). TL;DNR need to specify pip version to install packages correctly.

For python 2.7:

```
pip2.7
```