# "pip freeze" gives different modules from "help('modules')"

Tags: python, mysql, django, bash, virtualenv

I tried multiple solutions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739993/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-locally-installed-python-modules) and they seemed to give be different results. I am using `virtualenv` and I was wondering if it has something to do with that. The first method, from the python shell (while the virtual environment is active):

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
        for i in installed_packages])
print(installed_packages_list)
```

This gives the output

```
['distribute==0.6.34', 'django==1.8.1', 'flup==1.0.3.dev-20110405', 'importlib==1.0.3']
```

The second method, from the bash shell, again while the virtual environment is active:

```
pip freeze
```

This gives the following list:

```
Warning: cannot find svn location for flup==1.0.3.dev-20110405
Django==1.8.1
Ksplice-Uptrack==1.2.12
MySQL-python==1.2.2
PIL==1.1.7
South==0.7.6
distribute==0.6.34
django-photologue==2.4
dnspython==1.11.1
ethtool==0.6
## FIXME: could not find svn URL in dependency_links for this package:
flup==1.0.3.dev-20110405
importlib==1.0.3
iniparse==0.3.1
iotop==0.3.2
iwlib==1.0
mercurial==1.4
pycurl==7.19.0
pygpgme==0.1
pyzor==1.0.0
urlgrabber==3.9.1
virtualenv==1.9.1
yum-metadata-parser==1.1.2
```

Could someone explain why this is happening? Basically, I would like to be able to import packages from the second list, but I can't (in particular, my Django server is not able to import MySQLdb, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952187/getting-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb-have-tried-pre), even after trying their answers).

Answer (score 1):

Realized what the problem was...

```
pip -V
```

gave

```
pip 1.3.1 from /home/benjam15/.env/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
        (python 2.6)
```

while I was using python 2.7. Followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions) since the server's default "pip" command routed to python 2.6, while I really wanted stuff to install for python 2.7.